# Integrating HTML page into sap xcelsius

Tags: javascript, html, flash, xcelsius

I have a xcelsius dashboard with 5 tabs, 
My requirement is to add a new tab into "xcelsius dashboard" and load an HTML page into it, and page has lots of javascript and html components, like AJAX request, SELECT BOX, tooltips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't think that's an option. The most you could do, is to link to the HTML page with a URL button.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import full html and show it inXCelsius. Mind you that a SWF file , not a HTML browser. How ever you can bring data to the Xcelsius object using XML data and populate any Dropdown box etc